# PS - list permission granted to folders/subfolders

Tags: powershell

We are trying to somehow show what permissions have been granted to shared network drive.
Got the following script but throws errors that the dir is too long.

This may well be because as you can imagine, there are subfolders and subfolder under subfolders within the parent folder.  Yes, it is not well maintained unfortunately.

```
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path "\\abc-file1\Stocktake" -Recurse -Force
$Report = @()
Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
        {
            $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD
Group or
User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
            $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
        }
}
$Report | Export-Csv -path "C:\Logs\StockTakeAccessPermissions.csv"
```

Error:
`dir : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the  directory name must be less than 248 characters.`

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of information about a work around is available here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry - but the short version is to change your path to :

```
"\\?\\abc-file1\Stocktake"
```

make sure you have WMF5.1 or higher installed, and have the registry key :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled
(Type: REG_DWORD)

created and set to 1

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of hunting to find something that worked for me; most of what’s out there seems to say that you can't use the "extended-length path prefix" with `Get-ChildItem` - but it turns out that you actually can. You do need the registry key mentioned in [Keith Langmead’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176737/6083222), but the UNC prefix that seems to work is `\\?\UNC\Server\Share`, and you do need to add some additional parameters to `Get-ChildItem`: The command that worked for me to get all the directories (only) is

```
Get-ChildItem \\?\UNC\Server\Share -Include * -Directory -Recurse
```

The `\\?\UNC\` is literal; you need the three letters YOU EN SEE where shown.

Omitting the `-Include *` is enough to cause `Get-ChildItem` to return nothing at all.

<sup><sub>source of the information: https://igorpuhalo.wordpress.com/2019/08/29/overcoming-long-path-problem-in-powershell/ plus some experimentation</sub></sup>

Comment: I am not having much luck with that.
If you could share your code?

BTW. it is a Win Server 2012 R2 I am running it from.
Does that matter?

Comment: It shouldn't, but I won't rule out that it does. As far as my code, the only thing that you should change from what I gave you is `Server\Share` to whatever the root of your path of interest is. If any of the paths are likely to have spaces, I'd recommend quoting the entire root path, even if it doesn't have spaces.

Comment: You also may not need to pass `$folder.fullname` to `Get-ACL`; my experience seems to suggest that passing the folder object returned by `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-ACL` works just fine.